# Blender Animation Rig Goes Crazy with IK

Tags: armature

Does anyone know what could cause this?

When I drag the bone controlling upper arm it's like all the bones are glitching.

[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o902l5i2inlwqbd/rig.zip?dl=0)

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kvjpw0ctph6wvw/20230615-153522.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: it looks like there are several problems here, like your lower arm controller that is parented to the IK bone, or the upper arm that has a constraint but is also part of the IK chain, maybe tell what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as "first" help i would delete the parents of hand_ctrl_l + r

then you will get:

[image]

Comment: JesusChrist thank you so much this is exactly what i wanted to fix!